# The build in docker dns function is broken suddently

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I alway lookup the services each other by docker name in my system, things like : "curl http://contianer_name". Initially, All things is fine and It has worked for several months, But it is broken yesterday, Nginx could not bypass the url like http://contianer_name, And I could not curl successfully for the http://container_name in my host machine. What it is happen? :(,,,

docker network ls:

```
NETWORK ID     NAME                 DRIVER    SCOPE
ecbfafa9fccf   bridge               bridge    local
b1aac67cfbfa   myapp-api_default   bridge    local
5195101110d3   host                 host      local
d90ca5db218d   none                 null      local
```

docker network inspect

```
[
    {
        "Name": "myapp-api_default",
        "Id": "b1aac67cfbfa2923d5ae88a26e8729159f34e1ae083944e385a23047a7fc7237",
        "Created": "2022-09-28T18:21:57.202490009+08:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.22.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.22.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "850c8c091467b7c92aedff5631869ab2f5603ae48ee4a1efb7f18f2f890154ff": {
                "Name": "app-boot-system-sample",
                "EndpointID": "1497a7ac8726646f24bf82400d69c56bbcacb689d4423ab54db15af586373179",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c819074103a5b108d21b836afd1c156036e13f523b44eb5002e13edf48d9f825": {
                "Name": "sample-tenant-pc",
                "EndpointID": "d4ef531762a117132cbd40dee729cdf2458061e2444d35fc7968411676329e7b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "d04e0c550c95da196844c160ca9b9f80f99e3536f92da55d6e9f18533a381802": {
                "Name": "sample-event-pc",
                "EndpointID": "71bb31e965df8f47cfcc32685594803496bf77ad396854b5dc57851467f99996",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:07",
                "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.7/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ee6589ced2f5080b9f3641104262f430da8f37e1278f094f78a45e2414a607f4": {
                "Name": "app-boot-redis-sample",
                "EndpointID": "be41952c5709d7a843b9b2ce3276bd7ac8e951ab653ba478d3a8f7cf7fe9599a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "fd9196fc0fee67de364d6be37581e4fd9827b2983a332995269af78817828bbd": {
                "Name": "sample-org-pc",
                "EndpointID": "a0fd805ee5705533f58b7f0e3f1cbdb0a20abc1a01057bd23a2a5161d0c5181c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "myapp-api_default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "myapp-api",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.26.2"
        }
    }
]
```

Docker compose defined as below in  the project sample-tenant-pc:

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  sample-tenant-pc:
    build:
      context: .
    restart: always
    container_name: sample-tenant-pc
    image: sample-tenant-pc
    ports:
      - 9001:80
    networks:
      - myapp-api_default
      
networks:
  myapp-api_default:
    external: false
    name: myapp-api_default
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting the docker daemon?

Comment: yes，sudo systemctl restart docker

Comment: If you change the hypens to undersocres in container name? (for example sample_tenant_pc) and try to ping it from another container

Comment: I can ping successfully in container : 64 bytes from app-boot-system-sample.myapp-api_default (172.22.0.5): icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms. The problem might occured outside of container, but in host machine that I configured some code, like bypass in Nginx :   proxy_pass http://sample-org-pc/;

Comment: Sorry about that the code of 'proxy_pass sample-org-pc;' is also running in another nginx conttainer named 'production_nginx', I will check the ping command in that container

Comment: My God, I found the problem is dispear, The production_nginx container is present in the network inspect, but It is not yesterday, I thought the problem might because of the failure deploy of the nginx container and it cause by pass fail for every url in nginx